# Zooming in and out in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, scroll, zooming

I'm making a file where I need to be able to zoom in and out on an Image (Converted to a symbol and given an instance name) using the middle mouse scroller. I've written something similar to :

```
image1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, function1){
image1 = image 1 +50;
}
```

so all the scrolling works to increase the image size, but what can I do to make it where if I scroll back the mouse wheel, it scrolls out of the image?
From what I understand, there is no converse operation to MOUSE_WHEEL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [as3 mouse wheel reverse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876389/as3-mouse-wheel-reverse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MouseEvent::delta](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.htm) Indicates how many lines should be scrolled for each unit the user rotates the mouse wheel. A positive delta value indicates an upward scroll; a negative value indicates a downward scroll.

Check if event delta value is positive or negative and scale the image using scaleX and scaleY.

```
var zoomAmount:Number = 0.1;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, zooom);

function zoom(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if(event.delta > 0) {
        image1.scaleX += zoomAmount;
        image1.scaleY += zoomAmount;
    } else {
        image1.scaleX -= zoomAmount;
        image1.scaleY -= zoomAmount;
    }
}
```